# Android ActionBar background change don't work

Tags: android

I'm trying to change background color of action bar in my app and my styles.xml looks that:

```
<resources>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

    <!-- Main theme colors -->
    <!--   your app branding color for the app bar -->

    <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#71343e</item>
    <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
    <!--   native widgets will now be "tinted" with accent color -->
    <item name="colorAccent">#ff71bf41</item>

    <!--Action bar style-->
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar</item>

</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar.TitleText</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar.TitleText</item>
    <item name="android:height">100dp</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">#71343e</item>

</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar.TitleText" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#0d5875</item>
</style>
```

I'have tryed to use various color argument but anyone work. How I can change the ActionBar color?

Answer (score 0):

For **android version 3.0+**, this is one solution:

inside `res/values/themes.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar"
           parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

And set it to your whole application (or individual activities)

```
<application android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" ... />
```

For **android version 2.1+**, you have to modify it a bit

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar"
           parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

And

```
<application android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" ... />
```

You can find more information about styling the `ActionBar` [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html#AndroidThemes).

Comment: I tried using android:background but it didn't work too